# How to Boolean union thousands of objects?

Tags: python, modifiers

I am totally new to Blender and to Python. And coding in general... I have a building model exported from Autodesk Revit with lots of walls modeled as “butt jointed” rectangular boxes in mesh format. Not Brep. I need to union them all into a single solid without the intervening faces. They do not overlap but just have tangential faces at the intersections. The operation would have to pick a start point and then detect and progressively add a new connected object to the whole until it runs out.

Where do I start?

Thanks.

Comment: There might be an easier solution ready, but I would approach it by iterating over vertices and finding the nearest face for each. Once I would find a close face, I would seek connected vertices also close to that face until I close a loop. Then I would knife cut that loop onto that face, perhaps remove the inside of the cut, merge by distance…

Comment: Unless you really want to do it with code, I think you could just do it with a regular boolean modifier and set the `Operand Type` to `Collection`.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: yeah...but...if he is totally new to Blender and python....this won't help him much - i assume ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone!